# Dynamic function call with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-click

I have an array of

```
invitationList = ["A","B","C","D"]
```

from this array, I need to form a list having a name of **A/B/C/D** with button of **accept**. While clicking this accept button, accept function should be invoked.

I tried,

```
 var list_Invitation='';
 list_Invitation="<ul class='offline-invitation'>";
 var i = 1;
    for(var index in invitationList)
        {
        i++;
        list_Invitation=list_Invitation+'<li class="class_InvitationList"><h5>'+invitationList[index]+'</h5><input type="button" class="accept-btn" value="Accept" ng-click="acceptInvitation(\''+invitationList[index]+'\', \'accept-btn'+i+'\');"/></li>';
        }
            list_Invitation=list_Invitation+"</ul>";


$scope.acceptInvitation=function(name,id)
  {
      console.log('Invoked');
  }
```

List will be shown, but the function cannot be invoked while clicking the button.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: ok, what does final html look like?

Comment: [Final Html](http://jsfiddle.net/ct2ty/)

Comment: why are you using dom manipulation when you should be using ng-repeat ... if you create your own dom then you will have to compile the structure

Comment: @ArunPJohny How can I use ng-repeat on this

Comment: did you run it on IE browser? if not, please run there and let me know if you got any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular way is

```
<ul class='offline-invitation'>
    <li class="class_InvitationList" ng-repeat="item in invitationList">
         <h5>{{item}}</h5>
        <input type="button" class="accept-btn" value="Accept" ng-click="acceptInvitation(item, $index)" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

then in your controller

```
$scope.invitationList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

$scope.acceptInvitation = function (name, id) {
    console.log('Invoked', name, id);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8CD9/)

Comment: +1, It's really good, But the OP asked about dynamic function

Comment: @RameshRajendran Yes that is the caption... but from the question *accept function should be invoked*, I think OP just created the dom structure and appended it to the dom without compiling it... so the ng-click is not getting invoked

Comment: Okay, I will test this locally and will give solution to OP, cool

Comment: @RameshRajendran you can always use the attached fiddle to test the cases

Comment: I got an empty list? Is there any reason for this?

Comment: if you are getting an empty list then `invitationList` is empty... can you share your html and script

Comment: @Vinod check http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8CD9/9/ - use the track by option of ng-repeat

Comment: I want to remove `li` tag while clicking accept button. How Can I do this?

Comment: @Vinod http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/d8CD9/10/ - as the original problem is solved it will be better to ask a new question - it will increase the possibility of an answer because only I will be seeing this question